# If a complex analytic function is injective on a dense subset of an open connected domain, is it injective on the whole domain?

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $D$ be an open connected domain inside $\mathbb C$ and let $g: D\rightarrow \mathbb C$ be an analytic function. Suppose there is a dense subset of $D$ on which $g$ is injective. Does $g$ have to be injective on all of $D$?

This type of property is certainly false in general for continuous or real differentiable maps. For example, one can take $h(x)=(\cos x, \sin x)$ on $[0,2\pi]$. It's less clear to me in the complex analytic case. Though, I still think it is false in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated it is not true since one can take $f(z)=z^2$ on the unit disc and take the set $A$ which consists of points with rational coordinates in the right half of the disc $\Re z >0$ and points with irrational coordinates in the left half $\Re z <0$; obviously $A$ is dense and $f$ is $1-1$ on $A$

It is true if the dense set of injectivity $A$ is not "sparse" - for example, if for any open subset $U$ the measure of $U-A$ is zero.

first, it is clearly locally true in the sense that $f'(z) \ne 0, z \in D$ since near a critical point $f'(w)=0$ the local form of the function, $f(z)=f(w)+a(z-w)^{n+1}+O(z-w)^{n+2}, a \ne 0$ shows it cannot be injective but it is $n+1 \to 1$ where $n \ge 1$ is the order of the critical point, so in particular, there is a small open neighbourhood $U$ of $f(w)$ for which $f^{-1}(U)$ contains $n+1$ disjoint open subsets sent by $f$ into the same open set $W$ - the non-sparse hypothesis leads to a contradiction since if $U_1,U_2$ are two such disjoint open sets $f(U_1 \cap A) \cap f(U_2 \cap A)$ has full measure in $f(U_1)=f(U_2)=W$ so they cannot be disjoint

But now assuming $f(z)-c$ has two distinct zeroes $w_1,w_2$, using again the local form of $f$ at $w_1,w_2$, it follows that $f$ sends disjoint small neighbourhoods of $w_1,w_2$ into the same small neighborhood of $c$ again contradicting the hypothesis as above